# Wakeup freeze after suspend on desctop [nothing works]

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I have black screen after suspend on my desctop. So far i tried:
1. Different versions of ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04
2. Disable internal graphics
3. Switch to nvidia proprietary drivers
4. Edited grub file according to different instructions.

Nothing works for me, any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

My computer did the same thing I had to go into screensaver and tell it to do nothing or to never do any of the screensaver it works for me. It also makes it where you do not have to put in password in at the time the computer comes back up.